# Sending a list value via ajax to view in Django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, templates, view

I'm trying to send a list from template to view Django via ajax. After I send that, I get same list as a string format!

**index.html**

```
<script>
   ...
   var provinces_list = []
   var obj = document.getElementById('objectSelected');
   for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
        provinces_list.push(obj.options[i].value)
   }
   var jsonText = JSON.stringify(provinces_list);

   $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      data: {
         'P_list': jsonText
      },
      url: '{% url '...' %}',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (context) {
        ...
      }
   })
</script>
```

**view.py**

```
provincesList = request.GET.get('P_list')
```

when I debug, I get the list as str format:

`provincesList={str}'["X","Y","Z"]'`

I want to get value as a list. how can do that? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load it back from json:

```
import json

provincesList = json.loads(request.GET['P_list'])
```