# Getting multiple Items using getlist in Django not Working: Return []

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have an issue where the value of multiple item didn't reflect at all to my `views.py`

```
request.POST.getlist('listitems[]')
```

**Returns** when print

```
[]
```

**selected_items looks like** in my ajax when console

[image]

**ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'sales-item' %}",
    data:{
       listitems : selected_items, item_size: selected_items.length}

   }).done(function(data){ .........
```

**views.py** I want to insert it multiple to database but it seems before that happen when I tried to print the `item_list` it doesn't work it returs `[]` Did I miss something?

```
item_size = request.POST.get('item_size')
item_list = request.POST.getlist('listitems[]')

print(item_list) //doesnt work

for i in item_size:
      out_items = request.POST.getlist('listitems['+i+']')
      print(out_items)

      additems = table1(quantity = out_items[quantity])
      addsales.save()
```

Comment: you should print `request.POST`'s dictionary data to see what kind of data you are getting

Comment: @ruddra what do you mean? I already tried prinitng `item_list` using request.POST but it didn't reflect it prints like this `[]`

Comment: There could be a lot of things wrong in your code, but we can not tell exactly what or why. Maybe variable name is wrong, or the data is not coming or something else. So you have to debug it. print is one way of debugging. But better is to do it using a proper debugger like `pdb`. Alternatively, you can check your IDE for debuggers.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

ajax side to pass data this format.

```
listitems : selected_items.join(',')
```

view.py side.

```
item_list  = request.POST["listitems"]
item_list = item_list.split(",")
```

Comment: I tried this ,let say I have two data, then I tried to print your code item_list and the result is like this `['[object Object]', '[object Object]']`

Comment: how can I get the specific value through this? it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare it for sending.
JSON can help with that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    list = [1,2,3,4]
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/food_output',
        contentType:"application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({'list': list}),
        success: function (data) {
            //this gets called when server returns an OK response
            alert("it worked!");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("it didnt work");
        }
    });
});
```

its have a lot of references in SO, example:
[How to send a list from JavaScript to Django views.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67988581/how-to-send-a-list-from-javascript-to-django-views-py)

[Sending a list value via ajax to view in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75023955/sending-a-list-value-via-ajax-to-view-in-django)